# php subquery from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

**Groups**

1. groupid
2. groupname
3. validity

**usertable**

1. groupname
2. username
3. password

   ```
   $c=date(y-m-d);

   $a=$_REQUEST['user'];

   $b=$_REQUEST['pass'];

   $c=date(y-m-d);

   $sql="SELECT username,password,validity FROM usertable,groups WHERE username='$a' AND password='$b' AND validity > (select validity,groupname from groups where groups.groupname = usertable.groupname)";
   ```

how to write subquery in PHP to check `username`,`passoword` from `usertable` and `validity` from `groups` based on `groupname` related to `username` from `usertable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this. Use join

```
$sql = "SELECT username,password,validity   
 FROM usertable a join groups b on a.groupname=b.groupname
 WHERE username='$a' AND password='$b' 
 AND validity > '$c'"
```

Comment: For Ex..... I have a groupname 'ABCDE' and its validity is '2016-07-15' in groups table.....I have username ='XYZ' and password ='123' where username belongs to groupname'ABCDE'.. On query i have to check username,password from usertable and validity of that particular groupname from groups table...

Comment: above query is doing same.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this throws an error? When comparing a column to a sub select, both sides should be with the same amount and the same type of columns.

Here you compared `validity > validity,groupname` which is not valid

```
"SELECT username,password,validity   
 FROM usertable,groups
 WHERE username='$a' AND password='$b' 
   AND validity > (select validity from groups where groups.groupname = usertable.groupname)"
```

Note that if the sub query return more then one row, you should use an aggregation function or something to determine which value should be returned, like `MAX(validity)`

Comment: For Ex..... I have a groupname 'ABCDE' and its validity is '2016-07-15' in groups table.....I have username ='XYZ' and password ='123' where username belongs to groupname'ABCDE'.. On query i have to check username,password from usertable and validity of that particular groupname from groups table...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to find out the validity of user based on the group in which the user belongs.

```
$sql = "select u.username, u.password, g.validity from usertable u, groups g where u.groupname = g.groupname and u.username = '$a' and u.password = '$b'";
```

Comment: For Ex..... I have a groupname 'ABCDE' and its validity is '2016-07-15' in groups table.....I have username ='XYZ' and password ='123' where username belongs to groupname'ABCDE'.. On query i have to check username,password from usertable and validity of that particular groupname from groups table...